# POST data to api using nodejs for Outlook Add-ins

Tags: http-post, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to fetch api and POST data to that api in nodejs which i have created using yo generator.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which provides an interface for fetching resources (including across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used `XMLHttpRequest`, but the new API provides a more powerful and flexible feature set.

Comment: I ended up using `Axios` myself, I forget why, might have just been better documentation.